# What is causing my web service call to timeout?

Tags: iis-6, timeout, web-services

The web server is Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.  The web service is an ASMX running in .NET 4.0.

When calling the web service as the domain user named 'ALBERT' everything works successfully.

```
POST http://elvis.ecq.local/sems/Services/DecVotingService.asmx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.225)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GetEventDivisions"
Host: elvis.ecq.local
Content-Length: 449
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetEventDivisions xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><eventID>165</eventID><isGroupEvent>false</isGroupEvent><roUserName>ALBERT</roUserName><CHKSUM>3dcdaea4f9dbcaac689a4ce19c0fcd97</CHKSUM></GetEventDivisions></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

When the exact same call is made using the domain user 'DALRYMPLE' the request times out.

```
POST http://elvis.ecq.local/sems/Services/DecVotingService.asmx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.225)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GetEventDivisions"
Host: elvis.ecq.local
Content-Length: 452
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetEventDivisions xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><eventID>165</eventID><isGroupEvent>false</isGroupEvent><roUserName>DALRYMPLE</roUserName><CHKSUM>2de3f62d249a2024394e9c410e7904b9</CHKSUM></GetEventDivisions></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

The same PC is used on the same network for each test.  What is causing the request to timeout for one user and not the other?

**Update**

The same test using 'DALRYMPLE1' works successfully.

```
POST http://elvis.ecq.local/sems/Services/DecVotingService.asmx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.225)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GetEventDivisions"
Host: elvis.ecq.local
Content-Length: 453
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetEventDivisions xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><eventID>165</eventID><isGroupEvent>false</isGroupEvent><roUserName>DALRYMPLE1</roUserName><CHKSUM>87193ccb2f173499d03e2383d9a989f0</CHKSUM></GetEventDivisions></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

**Update**

It seems that it times out when the request has a Content-Length of 452.

**Update**

We have narrowed it down to the 3G modem used to connect to the server.  We have two types of modem - the newer modem fails when the request is 452 bytes whereas the older modem works successfully.  It is really strange.  We are investigating with the modem supplier.

The user DALRYMPLE also works correctly using a LAN connection.

Comment: What is the web service doing? Do you have control over it, or can you debug the service from that endpoint? If it is an external web service, what did support say?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect MTU, try picking it up or down by 1. see if it changes anything, QA for further issues and set it to a value that will not break.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't change that setting on the modem using the GUI but we are checking with the provider on whether the setting can be changed.  I'll award you the bounty and will confirm the answer once the problem is solved.